# Detect Fixed position JavaScript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

i use YS for fixed position menu, is working fine in firefox but not working in IE.

```
$(function(){                     // this is the shorthand for document.ready
  $(document).scroll(function(){    // this is the scroll event for the document

      scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();  // by this we get the value of the scrolltop ie how much scroll has been don by user
      if(parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80)         // check if the scroll value is equal to the top of navigation
      { 
          $("#navbar").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});       // is yes then make the position fixed to top 0
      }
      else
      {
          $("#navbar").css({"position":"absolute","top":"80px"}); // if no then make the position to absolute and set it to 80
      }
  }
}
```

Any solution fixing this problem for ie?

Comment: What version of IE? 6,7,8,9,10?

Comment: 6,7,8, dont have 9 to check   :S

Comment: Maybe ending the document.ready with a `});` can help.

Comment: FYI, Stackoverflow does not use pre and code tags.

Comment: @MirkoMukaetov: last two closing brackets both need to be `});`, also, add `var` tp `scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();` to avoid implied globals. and lastly: there is a difference between a fixed and absolutely positioned element.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem where to add var tp scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop(); can u write me full code please?

Comment: Note that `position: fixed` was only implemented in [IE7 and later](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html).

Comment: @MirkoMukaetov: the third line of your snippet is now `scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();`, it should be `var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();`. If not, strict mode will throw an error, and you're creating a global, which, in some cases (like `name` or `status`) can cause name conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, to me seems to be that IE doesn't trigger the `.scroll` event. At least, not in jsfiddle. If you explicitly trigger the event, that does seem to fix things. [this fiddle was tested in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/yCrtG/3/) and it works. The code:

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).scroll(function()
    {//add var here, avoid evil globals:
        var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();  
        if(parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80)         
        { 
            $("#navbar").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});       
        }
        else
        {
            $("#navbar").css({"position":"absolute","top":"80px"});
        }
    });//close properly
    $(document).scroll();//explicit call
});//close this, too
```

Comment: this works for me but in ie my menu goes to left margin 100px, should i add so,e left:0 or what?

Comment: I don't know where you want that element to go, but just work on the CSS rules, but changing `left` seems to be the logical next step to me, too

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ')' in your code [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCrtG/2/) (tested in IE7 and IE9)

```
$(function(){                     // this is the shorthand for document.ready
  $(window).scroll(function(){    // this is the scroll event for the document

      scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();  // by this we get the value of the scrolltop ie how much scroll has been don by user
      if(parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80)         // check if the scroll value is equal to the top of navigation
      { 
          $("#navbar").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});       // is yes then make the position fixed to top 0
      }
      else
      {
          $("#navbar").css({"position":"absolute","top":"80px"}); // if no then make the position to absolute and set it to 80
      }
  }); //here
});//here
```

Comment: this is ok but is not working for me in IE 7,8, Mozila is fine

Comment: @MirkoMukaetov I changed my code and it is working. instead of using document I am using window. check jsfiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

For position fix must your parent element has this style

```
position:relative;
```

best regards